# Make ScrollViewer with Canvas inside scrolling smoothly in code

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I make ScrollViewer scroll my Canvas smoothly in code (no xaml)?
As I know for xaml it needs to set ScrollUnit to "Pixel", but I can't do it in code.

Comment: Are you thinking of VirtualisingStackpanel.Scrollunit ? Which applies to a virtualizing stackpanel.  Please provide a minimal sample reproduces this issue. Just putting a path in a canvas inside a scrollviewer produces pretty smooth scrolling for me.

Comment: @Andy Example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n2dk069YwWBmkJzK8ZVxkLJHXBi5fMiZ/view?usp=sharing
Try to scroll with your mouse wheel - it is not smooth at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are after is moving the scroll one pixel with each mouse wheel turn here is the way.

Register to mouse wheel preview event.

```
<ScrollViewer Height="350" Width="525" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
    <Canvas Height="650" Width="510">
        <Button Name="b" Height="30" Width="525" Content="Button text"/>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Move the scroll by 1 pixel on each time the event fires and set it as handled.

```
private void ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
    double offset = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - Math.Sign(e.Delta);
    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(Math.Min(Math.Max(offset, 0), scrollViewer.ExtentHeight));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What value can I change to increase the speed?

Comment: Just multiply the Math.Sign(e.delta) with a number fitting your needs